# Child component not re-rendering when Parent component re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using redux for state management in my app. But after I dispatch an action only the parent component updates the children doesn't receive the new props or updates. I'm using react 16.2.0, Redux 3.7.2, react-redux 5.0.6. These are my components:

Parent component

```
class ConnectingItems extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.afterProds = this.afterProds.bind(this);
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.data = this.props.data.products;
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.data = this.props.data.products;
    }
    afterProds(){
        this.data = this.props.data.products;
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    handleSearch(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    render(){
        const products = this.props.data.products;
        const searched_products = this.data;
        console.log('rerendering in main')
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <div className="container">
                    <h5 className="center-align">
                        <Searchform data={products} new_data={this.handleSearch}/>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <ProductsList user_data={searched_products}/>
                <Modal
                    header='Add Product'
                    modalOptions={{
                        opacity: .0
                    }}
                    trigger={
                        <div className='fixed-action-btn action-button'>
                            <a className="btn-floating btn-large yellow darken-1">
                                <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    }>
                    <AddProducts afterProdAdd={this.afterProds}/>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Child componenet:

```
class ConnectingProductListing extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.afterEdit = this.afterEdit.bind(this);
    }
    handleDelete(id){
        this.props.deleteProduct(id);
        console.log('delete dispatched');
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newprops){
        console.log(newprops);
    }
    afterEdit(){
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    render(){
        let data = this.props.user_data;
        console.log('im re rendering')
        console.log(data);
        return(
            <div className="container section">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12">
                        {data.length < 1 ? 
                            <div className="col s12 center-align">
                                <p>
                                    <b>No Product here.</b>
                                </p>
                            </div>:
                            data.map(product => {
                                const name = product.name;
                                const quantity = product.quantity;
                                const price = product.price;

                                return(
                                    <div key={product.id} className="card center grey lighten-5 z-depth-1">
                                        <div className='card-content left-align'>
                                            <span className='card-title'>
                                                {name}
                                            </span>
                                            <span>
                                                Price: ${price}<br/>
                                            </span><span>
                                                Quantity: {quantity}
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='card-action center'>
                                            <div className='row'>
                                                <div className='col s12'>
                                                    <Modal
                                                      header='Edit Product'
                                                      modalOptions={{
                                                        opacity: 0.0
                                                      }}
                                                      trigger={
                                                        <button className='btn yellow accent-3 center'>Edit</button>
                                                      }
                                                      actions={
                                                          <div>
                                                              <Modal
                                                                header='Delete Product'
                                                                modalOptions={{
                                                                    opacity: 0.0
                                                                }}
                                                                trigger={
                                                                    <a className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat">Delete</a>
                                                                }
                                                                actions={
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <a className='modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat'
                                                                            onClick={() => this.handleDelete(product.id)}>Yes</a>
                                                                        <a className='modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat'>No</a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                }>
                                                                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this product? It can't be undone</p>
                                                              </Modal>
                                                              <a className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-yellow btn-flat">Close</a>
                                                          </div>
                                                      }>
                                                        <EditProducts product={product} afterEdit={this.afterEdit}/>
                                                    </Modal>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My reducer:

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case constants.ADD_PRODUCT:

            return {
                ...state,
                data: {
                    ...state.data,
                    products: [
                        ...state.data.products,
                        action.payload
                    ]
                }
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Initial state:

```
initialState = {
        data: {
            id: 0,
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
            products: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: 'product name',
                    price: 10,
                    quantity: 10,
                }
            ],

        }
    };
```

store:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducer/index";

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

also i'm only focusing on the add product action
Please guys help me

Comment: Avoid instance variables like `this.data`, use React state instead.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I see you added some code, but you're still missing the container? And your action (constant) definition code?

If you're using redux, then you should include the source code for your store and containers.

Most likely the issue is the first one at https://web.archive.org/web/20180304224831/https://redux.js.org/troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-i-dispatch-an-action:

> Redux assumes that you never mutate the objects it gives to you in the reducer. Every single time, you must return the new state object.

There are various suggestions there. If you include more code, I might be able to help more.